# Covering Index - Include columns

Tags: nonclustered-index

I have a table :

```
[sch].[Parent]
(
     ID Identity [INT] (PK),
     Name VARCHAR(100),
     Email VARCHAR(250),
     Active TINYINT,
     InsertedBy VARCHAR(100),
     InsertedDTM DATETIME,
     UpdatedBy VARCHAR(100),
     UpdatedDTM DATETIME,
)
```

This table has PK on the `ID` column and a UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED CONSTRAINT on `Name`.

When I query a normal SQL without a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ID, Name 
FROM sch.Parent
```

This query uses a Index Scan and this is the case when I use a `INNER JOIN` with another CHILD table which has an FK in another table

What covering index should I use so that there is Index Seek in case of normal query and INNER JOIN with another table as well?

```
SELECT
     b.Id AS 'ParentsChildId'
    , b.[Name] AS 'ParentsChildName'
    , a.Id AS 'ParentId'
    , a.[Name] AS 'ParentName' 
FROM 
    [sch].[ParentsChild] b 
INNER JOIN 
    [sch].[Parent] a 
ON  a.Id = b.Id 
WHERE 
    a.Active = 1 AND b.Active = 1
```

Comment: In SQL server the primary key is selected as the clustered key if you don't say otherwise. There is no need to add another index to handle your query if the primary key is the clustered key.

Answer (score 4):

(I'm assuming SQL Server in this answer, please clarify which RDBMS you're using if it's not SQL Server)

The index you want is:

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_Parent_Id]
ON [sch].[Parent] (Id) INCLUDE (Name)
```

You use `INCLUDE` when a column isn't being filtered on (isn't in the `WHERE` clause) but is being selected. `INCLUDE` means that the column will only be included at the leaf level of the index (it's a small efficiency saving, essentially). Also as noted, if you have a `SELECT` statement without a where clause, indexes will never be used (faster to just scan the table rather than muck about with an index). Index seek is only used when you're returning a comparatively small number of rows, for your sample query if most of your `ParentsChild` and `Parents` rows are marked as Active then the optimiser may well decide to index scan instead of seek. A query that would be more likely to get an index seek instead of scan would be something like:

```
SELECT
     b.Id AS 'ParentsChildId'
    , b.[Name] AS 'ParentsChildName'
    , a.Id AS 'ParentId'
    , a.[Name] AS 'ParentName' 
FROM 
    [sch].[ParentsChild] b 
INNER JOIN 
    [sch].[Parent] a 
ON  a.Id = b.Id 
WHERE 
    a.Active = 1 AND
    b.Active = 1 AND
    a.Id = 2
```

(getting the children of Parent ID 2)